# Retry teamcity build if tests failed with some threshold

Tags: testing, teamcity

Is there an option or a plugin to re-run/trigger a TeamCity build if a certain threshold of failed tests is reached.

e.g.

- 10 tests from 100 failed - do not retry build
- 11 tests from 100 failed - trigger build again

Comment: Did you get an answer? I am struggling find solution of this.

Answer (score 1):

A "Retry Build Trigger" will retry failed builds but there is no way to do this based on the number of tests that have failed.

[image: Retry build trigger configuration]

You could write something that monitors build runs and then retries them using the [TeamCity REST API](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API).